# 2-Player Pig Game Issue

Tags: java

So my assignment in my Computer Science 2 course is to make a two player pig game. I believe I have most of it figured out, but for some reason I'm getting some sort of semantic error. The code for Player 1 works just fine, but when it comes to Player 2 it won't quit even when I tell it to go back to Player 1. If you could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int player1TurnScore = 0;
    int player1TotalScore = 0;
    int player2TurnScore = 0;
    int player2TotalScore = 0;
    int dice;
    int dice2;
    String input = "r";
    char repeat;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random diceRoll = new Random();

    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Pig!\n");

    while(player1TotalScore < 100 || player2TotalScore < 100){
        // human's turn
        do{
            dice = diceRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + dice);

            if(dice == 1){
                player1TurnScore = 0;
                System.out.println("You lose your turn!");
                System.out.println("Your total score is " + player1TotalScore);
                break;
            }else{
                player1TurnScore += dice;
                System.out.println("Your turn score is " + player1TurnScore);
                System.out.println("And your total score is " + player1TotalScore);
                System.out.println("If you hold, " + player1TurnScore + " points will be added to your total score.");
                System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, or 'h' to hold.");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();
                repeat = input.charAt(0);

                if(repeat == 'h'){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice != 1);

        player1TotalScore += player1TurnScore;
        System.out.println("Your score is " + player1TotalScore);
        player1TurnScore = 0;

        if(player1TotalScore >= 100){
            System.out.println("Your total score is " + player1TotalScore);
            System.out.println("PLAYER 1 WINS!");
            break;
        }

        // Player 2's turn
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("It is Player 2's turn.");
        do{
            dice2 = diceRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + dice2);

            if(dice2 == 1){
                player2TurnScore = 0;
                System.out.println("You lose your turn!");
                System.out.println("Your total score is " + player2TotalScore);
                break;
            }else{
                player2TurnScore += dice2;
                System.out.println("Your turn score is " + player2TurnScore);
                System.out.println("And your total score is " + player2TotalScore);
                System.out.println("If you hold, " + player2TurnScore + " points will be added to your total score.");
                System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, or 'h' to hold.");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();
                repeat = input.charAt(0);

                if(repeat == 'h'){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice2 != 1);

        player2TotalScore += player2TurnScore;
        System.out.println("Your score is " + player2TotalScore);
        player2TurnScore = 0;

        if(player2TotalScore >= 100){
            System.out.println("Your total score is " + player2TotalScore);
            System.out.println("PLAYER 2 WINS!");
            break;
        }
    }
```

I hope I did the indentation right since this is my first post. Let me know if there are issues!

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: For indentation in Eclipse CTRL+A CTRL+I

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
}while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice != 1);
```

with just

```
} while(dice != 1);
```